# How to remove or set transparent background in icon (.jpg)

Tags: icons, transparent, jpeg

I have icon for my application which is picture in jpg format. In the picture is logo of my application which has oval shape. I want to remove white background from this picture. I have irfan view. Or maybe is the way to set transparent background.

Thanks

Comment: Open it in a graphics program such as Gimp, mask it, and save to a file format which supports transparency (Jpeg doesn't!)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

JPEG doesn't support transparency (at least not in the variant that's widely used and supported). You need to use either PNG with an alpha channel, or the Windows .ICO format, which essentially is a DIB with either a colour key, or an alpha channel. Or use SVG, which is a vector format, and supports transparent background.

Comment: Sorry but I'm not a graphic, I can do in photoshop I don't have gimp. Ok I change format to png

Comment: @Robert: That has nothing to do with GIMP or Photoshop. Anyway, SVG is a format that's understood by programs like Inkscape or Illustrator (it's a vector format). Photoshop does well support PNG and ICO.

Answer (score 27):

Simple, you can use site [LunaPic](http://www166.lunapic.com/editor/)

1. Upload->Edit->Transparent->Click on background of image
2. File->Save (choose .PNG)

Answer (score 1):

What format does your language/system want icons in?

Simply save in that format selecting 'white' as the transparent colour. Jpeg doesn't have transparency but very few languages use jpeg as an icon format

Answer (score 0):

If you want already transparent icons with lots of options here it is 
[Flaticon - Transparent HD icons](https://www.flaticon.com/)